# Unique Ids to bind radio buttons to text areas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a form with multiple yes/no radio buttons and text area I would like to disable ("grey out") when yes is selected and enable when no is selected.

What I have currently only works for the first text area, all other radio buttons only effect the first text area because they have matching ids.

This is my view I am using.

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>
              <div>
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.Questions[i].AnswerSelected, true, new { id = "radio" + i, @class = "class" + i, value = "yes",  }) Yes
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.Questions[i].AnswerSelected, false, new { id = "radio" + i, @class = "class" + i, value = "no" }) No
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(p => Model.Questions[i].ActionToTake, new { id = "text" + i })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I know I will need to generate unique ids somehow for each pair of radio buttons and bind them to the text area somehow. This is the script I'm currently using.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".class1").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() === 'True') {
            $("#text1").prop('readonly', true);
            $("#text1").css('background-color', '#EBEBE4');
        } else if ($(this).val() === 'False') {
            $("#text1").prop('readonly', false);
            $("#text1").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    });
})
```

Whats a good way to approach this? I'm still new to javascript so any additional explanation for what you're doing would be helpful.

Comment: use the i counter in the id `id='"radio"'.i.'"'`

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs and group each set, such as `<div class="group">radio, radio, text area</div>`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments, you do not need to have IDs unless you use them elsewhere. You can simply have a group, may be a `DIV` with a class and radio buttons and text area as the group children. Did you want something like this?

```js
$(function() {

    var $choices = $(".group").find(":radio");
    $choices.on("change", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var choice = $.trim( $this.val() );
        var tarea = $this.closest(".group").find("textarea");
        tarea.prop("readOnly", choice === "yes");
        if ( choice === "yes" ) {
            //do your stuff when val = yes
        } else {
            //do your stuff when val = no
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="no" />No
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="no" />No
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice3" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice3" value="no" />No
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice4" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice4" value="no" />No
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```